# How to zip two same length lists where first has 'None' values, in Python3?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, list, zip, nonetype

I'm iterating through excel sheets and loading data into dataframe. The idea was to create temporary dataframe for current sheet and append it to final dataframe which is gathering all data after each iteration (several excel files with few sheets inside).

The thing is that those excel sheets has data rows over 100 columns wide and part of columns has multi-indexes (like month > days ranges) with upper index in merged cells.

I unmerge cells, for cells which were merged I forward-fill the value it had when it was merged, and I read the values of both levels of indexes to two separate lists: header_lv1 and header_lv2

Lists are the same length, but the one made from top level of index has some 'None' values in places where index was just one level in excel.

I want to zip those lists to one list with "lv1 - lv2" values to end up with one level index for dataframe columns.
For now I have:

```
header_lv1 = [ws.cell(row=2, column=i).value for i in range(1, sumaInCol + 1)] # read first level of indexes to list
header_lv1.extend(['Typ', 'Typ']) # add two more columns
header_collection.append(header_lv1) # collect header of each opened sheet for comparison

header_lv2 = [ws.cell(row=3, column=i).value for i in range(1, sumaInCol + 1)] # read second level of indexes to list
header_lv2.extend(['Produkt', 'MP/H']) # add two more columns
header_collection.append(header_lv2) # collect header of each opened sheet for comparison

mi = list(zip(header_lv1, header_lv2)) # create list of tuples
ind = pd.Index([e[0] + '-' + e[1] for e in mi]) # want to create list with values made by concatenating tuples to string
```

### header_lv1

> [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Sierpień', 'Sierpień', 'Sierpień', 'Sierpień', 'Wrzesień', 'Wrzesień', 'Wrzesień', 'Wrzesień', 'Październik', 'Październik', 'Październik', 'Październik', 'Październik', 'Listopad', 'Listopad', 'Listopad', 'Listopad', 'Grudzień', 'Grudzień', 'Grudzień', 'Grudzień', 'Styczeń', 'Styczeń', 'Styczeń', 'Styczeń', 'Styczeń', 'Luty', 'Luty', 'Luty', 'Luty', 'Marzec', 'Marzec', 'Marzec', 'Marzec', 'Kwiecień', 'Kwiecień', 'Kwiecień', 'Kwiecień', 'Kwiecień', 'Maj', 'Maj', 'Maj', 'Maj', 'Czerwiec', 'Czerwiec', 'Czerwiec', 'Czerwiec', 'Lipiec', 'Lipiec', 'Lipiec', 'Lipiec', 'Lipiec', 'Sierpień', 'Sierpień', 'Sierpień', 'Sierpień', 'Wrzesień', 'Wrzesień', 'Wrzesień', 'Wrzesień', 'Październik', 'Październik', 'Październik', 'Październik', 'Październik', 'Listopad', 'Listopad', 'Listopad', 'Listopad', 'Listopad', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', 'PODSUMOWANIE W TERMINACH PROMOCJI', None, None, None, None, None, 'wyc', 'zam', 'wys', 'zre', None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Typ', 'Typ']

### header_lv2

> ['Miasto', 'Kanał komunikacji', 'Rodzaj', 'Typ', 'Opis/Nazwa', 'Komunikat', 'DMS', 'Rekrutacja', 'Nowa/ stara oferta', 'Osoba odpowiedzialna', '01-07', '08-14', '15-21', '22-28', '29-04', '05-11', '12-18', '19-25', '26-02', '03-09', '10-16', '17-23', '24-30', '31-06', '07-13', '14-20', '21-27', '28-04', '05-11', '12-18', '19-25', '26-01', '02-08', '09-15', '16-22', '23-29', '30-05', '06-12', '13-19', '20-26', '27-05', '06-12', '13-19', '20-26', '27-02', '03-09', '10-16', '17-23', '24-30', '01-07', '08-14', '15-21', '22-28', '29-04', '05-11', '12-18', '19-25', '26-02', '03-09', '10-16', '17-23', '24-30', '31-06', '07-13', '14-20', '21-27', '28-03', '04-10', '11-17', '18-24', '25-01', '02-08', '09-15', '16-22', '23-29', '30-05', '06-12', '13-19', '20-26', '27-03', 'liczba emisji', 'prasa - ilość modułów', 'WARTOŚĆ', 'cena jednostkowa(brutto)', 'do września', 'do października', 'do listopada', 'do grudnia', 'do 09 stycznia', 'do 15 lutego', 'do 11 marca', 'do 29 kwietnia', 'do 31 maja', 'do 15 lipca', 'do 10 sierpnia', 'do 19 września', 'do 30 września', 'po 30 września', None, 'wartość kampanii', 'Status', 'Wartość oszczędności', 'Rodzaj budżetu', 'Wycenione', 'Zamówione', 'Wysłane', 'Zrealizowane', 'Start działania', 'Realizacja działania', 'Kolejność', 'ga:campaign', 'ga:medium', 'ga:source', 'Produkt', 'MP/H']

Unfortunately I don't know how to deal with situation where tuple look like (None, 'Miasto') for example, which ends like that:

> ind = pd.Index([e[1] + '-' + e[0] for e in mi])
>   TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of python 3.6 you can use [formatted string literals, aka f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)

`ind = pd.Index([f"{e[0]} - {e[1]}" for e in mi])`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother, I've solved this by writing short function which changes None for empty srting '':

```
def checkForNone(list):
    """Function is changing None values for empty strings"""
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] is None:
            list[i] = str('')
        else:
            continue
```

and now just pass the lists to that function before converting them to lists of tuples:

```
header_lv1 = [ws.cell(row=2, column=i).value for i in range(1, sumaInCol + 1)]
header_lv1.extend(['Typ', 'Typ'])
header_collection.append(header_lv1)
checkForNone(header_lv1)

header_lv2 = [ws.cell(row=3, column=i).value for i in range(1, sumaInCol + 1)]
header_lv2.extend(['Produkt', 'MP/H'])
header_collection.append(header_lv2)
checkForNone(header_lv2)
```